# How do I turn off certain messages in AMPL?

Tags: output, ampl

I have an AMPL script that involves calling "solve" on a linear program many times.  The solver I'm using is MINOS.  After every time it solves, it outputs:

> MINOS 5.51:
>
> "option abs_boundtol 2.220446049250313e-16;" or "option
>   rel_boundtol 2.220446049250313e-16;" will change deduced dual values.

Is there a way to suppress this message?

I read this in the MINOS instructions:

> For invocations from AMPL's solve command or of the form
>
> minos stub ...
>
> (where stub.nl is from AMPL's -ob or -og output options), you can use
>   outlev= to control the amount and kind of output:
>
> outlev=0    no chatter on stdout
>
> outlev=1    only report options on stdout
>
> outlev=2    summary file on stdout
>
> outlev=3    log file on stdout, no solution
>
> outlev=4    log file, including solution, on stdout

which might be relevant but I don't understand it.

I have included "option solver_msg 0;" in my script; it turns off the announcement from MINOS that it got such-and-such an optimal value with so many iterations, but it doesn't affect the message I'm asking about here.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the remaining solver output to `/dev/null` (or equivalent for your system) as follows:

```
solve > /dev/null;
```

As for the message about `abs_boundtol` and `rel_boundtol`, I think you can set them to a small positive value larger than `2.220446049250313e-16` to make the message go away. Note that this will affect the dual values computed for presolved constraints.

See also https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ampl/ERJ8nF_LnNU/75yWK9deBjUJ

Comment: This successfully redirects the "MINOS 5.51:" line, but the other lines are still printing as before.  This makes me think they're printed by AMPL, not by MINOS (which makes sense after looking up what they mean), but I still can't figure out how to turn them off.  Thanks though; I didn't know you could redirect solver output like that - very handy!

Comment: @Water You are right, the message about options comes from AMPL itself. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

for me "option show_boundtol 0;" worked. You can try this. By default it is "option show_boundtol 1;".

You can read about it here (http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/netlib/ampl/changes)